# On a plane, can my friend sit in an unused seat next to me if we didn’t pay for seats?

Tags: air-travel, ryanair

If I am flying and allocate the middle seat, and the aisle and window seats are empty, can my friend, who’s sitting at the front come and sit in one of these seats, even though we didn’t pay for them?

Or is the airline, Ryanair going to be angry at this?

Comment: I have never seen middle seats being booked and window and aisle seats empty.

Comment: @Willeke Middle sears were allocated while the others were empty due to no allocation

Comment: Ryan air will be angry about anything from the moment you pay the ticket until the moment you get out of their face at the destination, they see passengers as an inconvenience and think you should be happy they allow you to travel with them as if they are doing you a favor